# Complex palindrome words

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a method who checks if it is a palindrome or not

```
public bool IsPalindrome(PalindromeModel model)
    {
        // First, check whether input string is null or whitespace.
        // If yes, then return false.
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.Value))
            return false;

        var inputDict = new Dictionary<char, int>();

        // Big/small letter is not important
        var lowerInputStr = model.Value.ToLower();

        // Fill input dictionary
        // If hit a space, then skip it
        for (var i = 0; i < lowerInputStr.Length; i++)
        {
            if (lowerInputStr[i] != ' ')
            {
                if (inputDict.ContainsKey(lowerInputStr[i]))
                    inputDict[lowerInputStr[i]] += 1;
                else
                    inputDict.Add(lowerInputStr[i], 1);
            }
        }

        var countOdds = 0;
        foreach (var elem in inputDict)
        {
            if (elem.Value % 2 != 0)
                countOdds++;
        }

        return countOdds <= 1;

     }
```

So it works with this words: `dood`,  `A Santa Lived As a Devil At NASA`

But for more complex palindromes like  `Mr. Owl Ate My Metal Worm` it returns false, but it should be true, how can I achieve this?

Comment: And now lets do the same it with an ASP.NET-driven web application...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the spaces and the punctuations before the first loop

```
var lowerInputStr = new string(model.Value
                      .ToCharArray()
                      .Where(c => !char.IsPunctuation(c)).ToArray())
                      .ToLower()
                      .Replace(" ", "");
```

Comment: And then you can make the logic a lot more simple.  Just take the length of the string and divide by 2.  Take that many characters from the start of the string and that many character from the end of the string.  Reverse one of them and check if they are equal.

You don't even need to check if it is and odd number of characters.  If the string was 12321, the length /2 = 2 (since it's an Int)  First 2 characters == last 2 character in reverse, the middle character doesn't matter.

Comment: Every time you create a character array, call ToLower, reverse a string, or do string replacement, you allocate a new string. FYI. May or may not matter in your case.

Answer (score 1):

That solution looks overly complex. I'd just walk in from both edges, skipping over any characters you don't define as being in scope for comparison. In this implementation, I only consider letters while ignoring case. Note that the solution doesn't allocate any additional memory (as for example `string.Replace()` or `string.ToLower()` do internally) and runs worst case input (it is a palendrome) in O(N).

```
bool IsPalendrome(string input)
{
    var left = 0;
    var right = input.Length - 1;

    while (left < right)
    {
        left = SkipNonLetters(input, left, 1);
        right = SkipNonLetters(input, right, -1);
        
        if (char.ToUpperInvariant(input[left]) != char.ToUpperInvariant(input[right]))
            return false;
            
        left++;
        right--;
    }
    
    return true;
}

int SkipNonLetters(string input, int startAt, int direction)
{
    while (startAt >= 0 && startAt < input.Length && !char.IsLetter(input[startAt]))
        startAt += direction;
        
    return startAt;
}
```

Examples:

```
Console.WriteLine(IsPalendrome("dood"));
Console.WriteLine(IsPalendrome("A Santa Lived As a Devil At NASA"));
Console.WriteLine(IsPalendrome("Mr. Owl Ate My Metal Worm"));
```

Output:

```
True
True
True
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on what Muhammad Sulaiman said, after you have the string cleaned up, the rest of the method can be a lot simpler

```
var lowerInputStr = new string(input.ToCharArray()
     .Where(c => !char.IsPunctuation(c))
     .ToArray())
     .ToLower()
     .Replace(" ", ""); 
    
return lowerInputStr.Substring(lowerInputStr.Length / 2) == (new String(lowerInputStr.Reverse().ToArray()))
.Substring(lowerInputStr.Length / 2);
```